# Can I run power cable through a large opening in a wall plate?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I've started remodeling the laundry room in my 60+ year old house where breaker box is. I made an opening below the box, to see how the wires were routed, so I could add a couple of circuits. I was going to drill a hole or holes for the Romex, but there is already a 1-1/2"(ish) hole in the bottom plate.

Should I just run the new wires down through it, or cap that plate with a short pc of 2x4 and drill smaller holes in it, for the new wires?

[image]

Comment: Personally I would cover the hole and drill smaller holes in the cover - not for any electrical/code reason, but just because ideally, you want *fewer* holes, to keep out rodents and other pests, reduce drafts, as well as to slow fire progress.

Comment: If the Question really is "Can I run power cable through a large opening in a wall plate?" then the useful Answer might be "Yes, of course… and why might you want to?"

Answer (score 11):

There's no problem using that hole, but **you'll need to keep the cable centered** to meet modern code. This is to avoid damage from fasteners. If you were to finish that wall and install baseboard trim with a nail gun, for example, you wouldn't want to be punching drywall screws or brads into your wires. Your idea to lay a block over and drill smaller holes would do, but it's maybe more work than necessary. Do whatever seems easiest.

Use the hole, but lay a two-by block along the near side (where the hole approaches the edge of the plate) to keep cables roughly centered.

[image]

Or staple the cable wherever it's convenient to accomplish the same.  You could stand a stub of 2x4 stud alongside for that.

[image]

Comment: I'd wonder how soon it needs to be fastened after going through a penetration. But if you clamp there anyway you can't go wrong, +1.

Comment: I don't believe there's any such rule as long as you follow more general rules, such as `every 48"` and `at a box entrance` (paraphrasing).

Answer (score 6):

Would use it, unless you want to do more work.  It has another board giving it more support.

If it was a joist or stud then it would need to be repaired, since they have more stress on them.

Comment: If you're worried about the wires being loose in the hole, you could always clamp them to the wall above and/or below the hole, but it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I would perhaps put the romex through a short piece of pipe and site that in the hole, then use spray foam to close up the gaps.  Or even a round plug of wood in the big hole.